# Blogspot Simple Template, centered background

Tags: css, background, blogger, blogspot

I've recently gotten back into blogging, but I'm a bit rusty on HTML/CSS specifics and have run into a little obstacle. I'd like this background image to be centered and repeating vertically so it "borders" the content, and I thought I had done everything right in the CSS, but the background disappears into the header area. I'm quite certain that I've made it wide enough. Any suggestions?

I have this in my CSS under the Template Designer:

```
body {
background-image: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/b81xrs.png);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: repeat-y; }
```

http://www.nikkipryde.net (as you can see, where the entries are the background is working as I want it to, but it isn't working that way at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this style:

```
.body-fauxcolumn-outer .cap-top
```

There is a height: 400px declaration that you would have to remove or set to height: 0.

Comment: @NikkiPryde: Please select it as an answer if it has helped you.